# Redirect to log in screen for unauthenticated user (react-native, react-navigation, react-redux)

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

My react-native app allows people to use it without logging in, but some screens require the user to be logged in to access. I'm using react-navigation, and when an unauthenticated user navigates to one of these screens, I want to redirect to the log in screen.

Right now, the screen simply renders differently for a logged out user, but ideally it would not render at all (just redirect):

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import ProfileScreen from './ProfileScreen';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { currentUser } = state;

  return {
    currentUser,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProfileScreen);


// ProfileScreen.js
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

const ProfileScreen = (props) => {
  if (props.currentUser == null) {
    return <Text>You are not logged in</Text>;
  }

  return <Text>Your Profile</Text>;
};

export default ProfileScreen;
```

Where is the proper place to put the redirect? I'm also using redux, so I've seen suggestions to put it in the componentDidMount of the container, or somewhere in the redux chain.

Comment: Hi. A chance that you could share an example of the full implementation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should keep a check in your `ProfileScreen` component's `componentDidUpdate` method to detect whether there is a `currentUser` in your redux store.

When the user is logged out, simply reset the navigation state to `Login` screen. In your component's `componentDidUpdate`,

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
   if(!this.props.currentUser){
      const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' })],
       });
      this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
  }
}
```

This will reset the navigation state and navigate to `Login` screen.

PS. If your `Login` screen is in another stack, add prop `key:null` in the `resetAction` params. This will reset the main app navigator and then navigate to `Login` screen.

Comment: That won't trigger once the screen is already mounted (including when the user is logged out from the screen itself). Should I put the same redirect in `componentDidUpdate()` as well, or redirect from the logout action creator?

Comment: Ohh sorry I meant `componentDidUpdate` ! Yes you can keep this check in `componentDidMount` as well. I have updated the answer

Comment: It seems it actually would need to go in both, because `componentDidUpdate` doesn't fire when it is first mounted.

Comment: Yup you would need it in both of those lifecycle methods